# AVCaptureSession stops when changing input type

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avcapturesession

In my Swift project, I have a camera feature. The camera is used to video recording with a basic start / stop - record button and a preview of the video. Everything works except one thing. I have a `UIbutton` which will switch between the front and the back camera of the phone. The the target function works as expected when the `AVCaptureSession` is not running. But after it is started, the button will stop the `AVCaptureSession` instead of just changing the camera.

Here's my function (the one triggered by the switch-button):

```
@objc func switchCameraClicked() {
    let session: AVCaptureSession = captureSession
    session.beginConfiguration()


    if (captureDevice?.position == .front) {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
    } else {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)
    }

    if let inputs = session.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
        for input in inputs {
            if input.device.deviceType != AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInMicrophone {
                session.removeInput(input)
            } else {
                print("Keep the microphone!")
            }
        }
    }


    do {
        try session.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!))
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()
    captureSession = session
}
```

**EDIT:**
The `AVCaptureSession` stops at `session.removeInput(input)` and triggers the `func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?)` delegate method.

Let me hear your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change camera capture device while recording a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467093/change-camera-capture-device-while-recording-a-video)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864372/switch-cameras-with-avcapturesession

Comment: None of the links have been relevant so far. Please check my update.

Comment: @SimonDegn have you found a solution? Just experiencing the same issue with stopping when call session.removeInput()